# How to trace/fix an SQL syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento

I'm trying to import a huge database file to my local dev environment to fix some errors I'm getting on the Magento back-end. I fixed the issue where it wouldn't import based on size, time, and memory. Now I've uncovered this gem of an error which says that my SQL syntax is wrong.

Not sure how that's possible because this is the exact file we're using in production but still, it's driving me nuts. Any help is appreciated.

SQL query:
DELIMITER ; ;

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER
>   trg_catalog_prod' at line 1

```
    DELIMITER ;;

    /*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_website_after_insert
    AFTER INSERT
    ON catalog_product_website FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `cataloginventory_stock_status_cl` (`product_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`product_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_index_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`product_id`);
```

Comment: remove the second `;` after `delimiter`

Comment: How is it an error? It is part of auto generated script by `mysqldump`. But there seems to be a bug in mysqldump to export routines. Bug [*66035*](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66035), Bug [*65394*](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65394) are some examples.

Comment: YOU'RE THE MAN JUERGEN!!!!

Comment: A note to anyone else with this problem: even if you shut everything down and do an htcacheclean, if you have a web server upload directory setup you should use the Browse File instead. The old sql file will still be cached, even if you remove the extra ; and save it.